# localStorage.getItem() react returning undefined before graphql query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, auth0

Using **graphql, react, and auth0**.

When a **user logs in** from auth0 the token is added in `localStorage.setItem('user_email', authResponse.email)`

**Then they go to the main page** where I have this graphql Query:

```
 export default graphql(USER_QUERY, {
       name: 'userQuery',
       skip: () => (localStorage.getItem('user_email') === null ||
                    localStorage.getItem('user_email') === 'undefined'),
       options: ()=>{
          return { variables: {email: localStorage.getItem('user_email')}}
       })(Component)
```

**The problem is**, the query never executes because the `getItem()` returns the email too late. Instead I get an error that it attempts to send `undefined` .

**How can I wait for localStorage?** Can a `promise` resolve afterwards? Should I use `componentDidMount(){}` in some way?

**I tried but was unsuccessful at** getting `this.props.userQuery.refetch()`, I will have `setTimeout()` to refetch with new variable but I couldn't write it correctly or get it to work.

**EDIT** Below is the Auth.js file for setting the session:

```
setSession(authResult) {
    //return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
    // Set the time that the access token will expire at
    let expiresAt = JSON.stringify(
        authResult.expiresIn * 1000 + new Date().getTime()
    );
    localStorage.setItem('access_token', authResult.accessToken);
    localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
    localStorage.setItem('expires_at', expiresAt);
    localStorage.setItem('user_email', authResult.idTokenPayload.email)

    history.replace('/dashboard/home')
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code of the login call and transition to main page?

Comment: I'm not sure why you have the `localStorage.getItem('user_email') === 'undefined'` condition, are you really expecting the `'undefined'` string or should it be `localStorage.getItem('user_email') === undefined`? Also, if you only do `localStorage.setItem()` and `localStorage.removeItem()` it should be either `null` or a string value that you set.

Comment: @AdamPatterson I just added it, the undefined part is to make sure it doesn't try to query with undefined as the result, because if it doesn't, the query doesn't happen because it just becomes skipped entirely.

Comment: @KevinDanikowski though like tudorpavel is saying, it should be `NULL`. Localstorage returns `NULL`, not undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I found a couple resources saying you can't make an async call with graphql queries, so nonetheless it will always be skipped. Instead, I had the query get called on `componentDidMount()` like so:

```
componentDidMount(){
        const checkEmailAndQuery = () => {
            if(this.state.userId === null) {
                if (localStorage.getItem('user_email') !== null) {
                    this.props.client.query({
                        query: USER_QUERY,
                        variables: {email: localStorage.getItem('user_email')}
                    }).then(({data}) => {
                        this.setState({userId: data.user.id})
                    })
                } else {
                    setTimeout(checkEmailAndQuery, 200)
                }
            }
        }
        checkEmailAndQuery()
    }
```